# С++ как язык прикладной разработки умер?

Tags: c++

Взгляните хотя бы на наш раздел C++. 
Большинство вопросов примитивные, явно студентов, делающих лабораторные работы. 
Взять хотя бы последние 3 вопроса. На такие вопросы даже не хочется отвечать. Они напишут с горем пополам свои лабораторки и забудут С++, как страшный сон.

А в англоязычном разделе С++ вопросы такие, что хрен разберешь, не для среднего ума.
Если взглянуть на раздел C#, то там вопросы совсем другие - вопросы использования прикладных технологий, GUI, библиотек, баз данных.

На С++ перестали писать обычный прикладной софт?

У меня есть опен-сурс проект на С++. Программа для Windows.

За всё время его существования НИ ОДИН человек ни предложил ни одного коммита/патча в С++ код, да хотя бы взглянул на этот код. Хотя ей активно пользуются, пишут свои xml-файлы для поддержки других хостингов, некоторые даже скрипты на языке [Squirrel](http://squirrel-lang.org) пишут. Конечно, я её практически не раскручивал, и пользователи в основном из xUSSR, но всё же.

Для сравнения, аналогичная программа на C# (более популярная, хотя, на мой взгляд, менее понятная простому пользователю) имеет целых 42 контрибутора!!!

Comment: Мне кажется, что ваш вопрос не намного лучше. Это ближе к обсуждению тематики подсайта в "мете"

Comment: Вопрос не про раздел на Stackoverflow, а про язык C++.

Comment: я думаю это просто системное программирование успехом перестает пользоваться все в веб программирование уходят там продукты проще и востребованней.

Comment: На мой взгляд ваш вопрос годится для форума программистов, но не для сайта "вопрос-ответ". Вот если бы у вас в вопросе была конкретная проблема с куском кода, тогда тут самое место

Comment: Вот видите, уже и минусы пошли. Это не я, честно :)

Comment: Да ладно вам, здесь же спрашивают и общие вопросы, давайте пообсуждаем.

Comment: Я не против пообсуждать. Но как-то я вижу что общих вопросов тут ну слишком много и еще уйма вообще не в кассу. Подсайт так превратится в болото.
По сути вопроса: "прикладная" ниша сползает в веб. Проще разрабатывать и проще монетизировать

Comment: Не, этот вопрос на stackoverflow никак не подходит. Конечно, на русской версии всё может быть, но на большом SO вопрос удалили бы за считанные секунды.

Comment: А для какого сайта этот вопрос подходит? Для http://programmers.stackexchange.com ? Я там не вижу русской версии.

Comment: @tutankhamun и Igor Chubin (оказывается здесь уже нельзя упомянуть более одного автора), вот не станет таких вопросов (т.е. их начнут удалять в считанные секунды) и очень быстро сайт превратится в такую же бесполезную помойку, как был Q&A от google.ru. / Надеюсь, не надо разжевывать -- почему.

Comment: @avp: я согласен, что не смотря на то что данный вопрос слабо подходит для Q&A формата (вне зависимости от тематики), его можно оставить (до тех пор пока таких вопросов не станет слишком много по сравнению с вопросами из тематики родительского Stack Overflow). Но можно ли [разжевать на Мете для ясности в чём полезность таких вопросов](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/107/23044)

Comment: @jfs, не думаю, что указанное Вами место на Мете подходит для такого обсуждения (там это будет совершенно бессмысленно). По делу кратко могу сказать, что ценность таких вопросов опосредованная, скорее психологического плана (и в основном для автора вопроса, особенно если он не остался без ответов), но в конечном итоге они повышают средний уровень участников форума.

Comment: @avp: ссылка, которая я дал, обсуждает *какие вопросы считать подходящими по тематике* на Stack Overflow на русском. Если Вы явно не про комментируете, то я думаю все вопросы-обсуждения по "мягким" (человеческий фактор) тематикам, ответы на которые зависят в основном от мнения (меньше опоры на факты и опыт разработки) и где нет одного объективно правильного ответа, останутся за бортом.

Comment: @jfs, да, конечно, они будут выброшены за борт. / А через некоторое время люди, которым такие вопросы были интересны (просто в плане чтения дискуссий) и которые попутно отвечали на конкретные вопросы новичков будут тратить свое время где-то в других местах. / Чем-то мне это напоминает процесс перехода к ЕГЭ в школах.

Comment: @avp: я не понимаю. "они будут выброшены за борт" -- [пройдите по ссылке и выскажите своё мнение, и будущее покажет](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/107/23044)

Comment: @jfs, там ведь обсуждение конкретного вопроса -- перевод справки. Совершенно не хочу переносить это обсуждение (да, пожалуй и продолжать его) туда. Не вижу практического смысла.

Comment: @avp: Там чёрным по белому написано: "предложите ваше содержимое". Английский вариант просто за основу взят. Не обязательно всю справку писать достаточно комментарий оставить в поддержку вопросов-опросников. Участников сейчас не много каждый голос заметен.

Answer (score 9):

Я бы не стал делать каких-то категоричных суждений (что дескать, да, умер, несите гроб, будем закапывать или напротив, живее всех, я вчера его в магазине в очереди за пивом видел).

Однако тенденция такая явно есть. Причин тому достаточно - это и порог вхождения, который явно выше, чем у java, c#, python или php, и отсутствие поддержки большой корпорацией (как в случае Microsoft и C# или Oracle и Java) и то, что популярные нынче направления прочно застолблены за другими языками (а это мобильная и веб-разработка, где позиции С++ не сказать что сильны), и тяжкий груз обратной совместимости, который не позволяет взять и просто забыть о тяжелом наследии мезозойского периода, что также усложняет язык.

В итоге так и получается, что С++ находит применение в более специфических областях, нежели те, что нынче являются стандартом де-факто.

Впрочем,  значимость тематики вопросов на этом форуме я бы переоценивать не стал. Тут скорее имеет смысл смотреть на рынок труда - где, для чего и в каких количествах требуются С++-программисты (однако сюрприза тут тоже не будет - нужно их существенно меньше, чем phpшников или джавистов).

В целом, думаю, вы правы, но драматизировать я бы не стал

Answer (score 8):

Проблема крестов в том что там слишком много возможностей из-за необходиомсти поддержки совместимости с С, добавления ООП, шаблонов и лямбд в поздних версиях стандарта.

В них одновременно коварно сосуществуют взаимоисключающие или частично дублирующие друг друга сущности вроде virtual и указателей на фукнции, шаблонов и препроцессора, лямбд и императивности C, malloc и new, printf и cout, namepspace и #include и.т.д и.т.п.

В довершении ко всему С++ очень популярно в ВУЗах. В результате при вываливании всего этого на плохо разбирающегося в сути дела студента мы и получаем все прелести http://govnokod.ru/cpp .

Количество всевозможных комбинаций разных сущностей языка грубо говоря растет как факториал от их количества.

C++ конечно примечательный язык, но чтобы писать на нем хорошие программы нужно постоянно бороться с ним же самим, пытаясь правильно подобрать нужную комбинацию из десятка если не больше возможных вариантов, так чтобы это выглядело хорошо в данной ситуации. Поэтому я его не люблю и предпочитаю обычный С.

Но не думаю что он умрет или внезапно исчезнет в ближайшее время. На нем так или иначе написано очень много кода и он вполне годен для практически любых прикладных проектов будь то компьютерные игры, графические оболочки, медиа-проигрыватели, браузеры и.т.д.

**UPD:** В подтверждении моих слов можно рассмотреть отношение числа сочетаний(биномиальных коэфициентов) для двух ключевых слов в C и С++:

```
C_c++(84,2)/C_c(32,2) = 1743/248 ~= 7
```

Да, кресты в 7 раз сложнее обычного C.

Ключевые слова взяты отсюда: [C](http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/keywords.html) и
[C++](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword)

Answer (score 5):

Я думаю, что интересных вопросов по C++ (и Си) мало не потому, что на этих языках мало пишут, а потому, что те кто их использует, просто неплохо владеют языком. По крайней мере тем подмножеством языка, которое вполне им достаточно для решения практических задач.

А вот почему здесь действительно мало *интересных* вопросов  не связанных напрямую с языком (да, конкретный язык может быть важен, но все же он не первичен), таких как обсуждение идей, да и технических тонкостей реализации практических задач -- вот это действительно вопрос (конечно, для Меты).

Впрочем, ответ (видимо активного большинства SO) очевиден -- формат Q&A не предусматривает... и т.п.

Answer (score 3):

В *чистом* виде -- возможно, вы не сможете написать полноценное ПО с пользовательским интерфейсом без использования дополнительных возможностей из фреймворков или библиотек.

Собственно, могу напомнить о существовании изумительного (не побоюсь этого слова) фреймворка **Qt** (читается: кьют), который улучшает и облегчает разработку на C++ (собственно, в своё время я остановился на C++ исключительно из-за Qt).

**Некоторые преимущества Qt:**

- Qt широко используется для разработки прикладного ПО, запускаемого на различных программных и аппаратных платформах с минимумом изменений в основной кодовой базе, или и вовсе без них, при этом сохраняя силу и скорость нативных приложений.
- Единый код для множества платформ и всех видов устройств: X11 (GNU/Linux, FreeBSD, HP-UX, Solaris, AIX и т.д.), Embedded Linux, Android, OS X, iOS, Windows (XP, Vista, 7, 8), Windows RT (win8 apps и phone 8.1), QNX / BlackBerry 10, Wayland, etc.
- Помимо этого, Qt является основой для многих интерфейсов операционных систем. Из основных: Ubuntu (Unity 8/Next), KDE, Sailfish.
- Лицензии: LGPL, GPL и коммерческая (содержит дополнительные возможности).
- Отличная документация.
- Qt позволяет на всех этапах ускорить процесс создания программного обеспечения, повысить его эффективность и, как следствие, значительно сократить время, затраченное на реализацию проекта при разработке.
- Сообщество насчитывает более 800.000 человек и продолжает расти. Согласно данным официального сайта, "95% довольных пользователей -- качество, подтверждённое успешным опытом разработчиков".
- Расширение, улучшение, облегчение C++. Более 700 C++-классов.
- Qt Quick и декларативный язык QML для создания UI и логики. Возможна интеграция с C++. Итого, можно бОльшую часть кода написать на QML (JavaScript) с некоторыми "вкраплениями" C++.

Из минусов Qt могу отметить разве что отсутствие его в вебе (есть проект по переносу QML в web, но пока на ранней стадии) и излишний вес (например, ~10 МБ apk), что, впрочем, не является особой проблемой в современном мире.

**Вывод:** C++ актуален (особенно после нововведений C++11 и C++14). Плюс есть Qt (в некотором роде, "надстройка" над C++), который более чем пригоден для разработки прикладного ПО и является одним из лучших решений вообще.

Answer (score 2):

Я считаю, что не умер, но значение его сильно уменьшилось по сравнению с прошлым. На сегодняшний день С++, как мне кажется, берут для разработки прикладных приложений только в нескольких случаях. К примеру требование мультиплатформенности и требование высокой скорости работы.

Благодаря Qt на С++ можно писать весьма комфортно, но всё же этот язык не столь прост в освоении как Java, C# и многие другие. К тому же С++ (как мне кажется) не очень приспособлен для вэба, а многие приложения на сегодняшний день именно на это и ориентируются.

2 года назад я тут задавал вопрос про ORM-Framework'и для C++, но мне так никто толком ничего не смог ответить. Начал более подробно искать сам и понял, что ORM на С++ лучше вообще не использовать... :( Похожая история была когда задумался о том как писать вэб-сервисы на С++. Понял, что геморой тот еще... Погоревал и пошел писать на C# за считанные минуты (при помощи WCF писать вэб сервисы просто сказка).

Многие другие языки разработки выигрывают у плюсов в скорости разработки, а на сегодняшний день это очень важный фактор. Свою роль играет и не хватка айтишников по всему миру. Программистов набирают даже из всякого сброда и порог вхождения в язык тут выше чем у той же явы.

Кроме того мне кажется, что читабельность кода на С++, скажем так, оставляет желать лучшего, но это может быть и дело вкуса. Компиляторы под С++ тоже не "айс" - часто и густо не говорят вовсе в чём ошибка, а лишь выдают какую-то весьма абстрактную информацию. Примитивнейшие ошибки из-за этого могут замедлить разработку на многие минуты, а то и часы (зависит от опыта). Безопасность приложения написанного на плюсах так же зависит от опыта и знаний программиста - сам по себе язык из-за обратной совместимости весьма дырявый.

Всегда хотел заниматься разработкой прикладных приложений и во время учёбы я честно и от всей души пытался найти веские причины почему мне стоило бы специализироваться на плюсах. Так и не нашел... Мультиплатформенность нужна слишком редко, что бы тратить такие усилия. При нынешних мощностях вычислительной техники большой роли скорость загрузки приложения не играет. Даже +-5 секунд в этой области (в большинстве случаев) не оправдывает высоких ресурсных затрат при разработке.

P.S. Всё выше сказанно лишь отражает мнение автора и не претендует на истину в первой инстанции ;)

Answer (score 1):

Наверное это очень удобная позиция - посылать через браузер, написанный на C++, сидя в оконном менеджере, написанном на C++, запрос веб-серверу, написанному на C++, который передается в приложение на C#, виртуальная машина которого написана на C++, которое сохраняет вопрос в базу данных, написанную на C++, что на С++ не пишут прикладного софта :) Пишут.

Comment: Весь этот софт — legacy. Вопрос о перспективах. И да, большая часть стека .NET компилируется C#-ом или C++/CLI (это **не** C++), вот [исходники](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/tree/master/src).

Comment: @VladD, весь этот софт просто нельзя назвать прикладным (о чем и был вопрос).

Comment: прикол в том, что все эти вышеназванные приложения - браузер, веб-сервер, субд пишутся в количестве единиц или десятков, а вот сайтов, веб-приложений  и мобильных разработок создается миллионы штук. Почувствуйте разницу